# tkinter progressbar with text inside it

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter, progress-bar

```
import Tkinter
import ttk
def main():
  root = Tkinter.Tk()
  root.geometry("500x200")
  ft = ttk.Frame()
  ft.pack(expand=True, fill=Tkinter.BOTH, side=Tkinter.TOP)
  pb_hd = ttk.Progressbar(ft, orient='horizontal', mode='indeterminate')
  pb_hd.pack(expand=False, fill=Tkinter.BOTH, side=Tkinter.TOP)

  pb_hd.start(50)
  root.mainloop()
if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

I want to add text inside the progress bar but not getting any idea how to do it?

Comment: You can accomplish this by [applying a tkinter style to your progressbar widget](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47902046/3994202).

Answer (score 2):

The ttk progressbar does not support a text option. You can create a label and pack it immediately above or below the widget.