# Make tkinter label fill with color like a loading bar

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, label

Is it possible to make a Label with text in it fill up with for example green depending on a percentage? Like if the percentage is 50% the labels left half is filled with green?

I thought of making a Label with the color transparent and lay it over the original label, but it seems tkinter doesnt have transparent labels.
You also cant seem to change the width of a label at runtime, which would also be necessary to adjust it when the percentage changes.

Is there any way to do what I described in tkinter? It seems not.

Comment: Why don't consider about `ttk.progressbar` directly?Do you want to put a text on a progressbar?

Comment: You can try a progressbar with text mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47896881/progressbar-with-percentage-label?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: I didnt find this, thank you very much. I will try this.

Comment: Under the right circumstances you can change the width of widgets at runtime, though that depends on how you've laid out the widget on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

A simple trick is to use `place` to put a duplicate label on top of the original label. You can then use `place` options to control the size of the overlay.

The following example shows 60% progress (`relwidth=.6`). You can use `place_configure` to change the percentage at runtime to be any value you want.

```
label = tk.Label(root, text="Hello, world", borderwidth=0)
label.pack(padx=20, pady=20)

progress_label = tk.Label(label, text="Hello, world",
                          background="green", borderwidth=0, anchor="w")
progress_label.place(x=0, y=0, anchor="nw", relwidth=.6)
```

[image]