# Python TKinter progress bar label not acting correctly

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, progress

I have really simple program with two progress bars in a window. I try only update the first progress bar, but the second progress bars label updates as well, when it shouldn't.

I am using j_4321's answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47896881/progressbar-with-percentage-label) post on progress bar labels.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()


# Progress bar #1
style_1 = ttk.Style(root)
style_1.layout('text.Horizontal.TProgressbar',
               [('Horizontal.Progressbar.trough',
                 {'children': [('Horizontal.Progressbar.pbar',
                                {'side': 'left', 'sticky': 'ns'})],
                  'sticky': 'nswe'}),
                ('Horizontal.Progressbar.label', {'sticky': ''})])
style_1.configure('text.Horizontal.TProgressbar', text='0 %')
variable_1 = tk.DoubleVar(root)
pbar_1 = ttk.Progressbar(root, style='text.Horizontal.TProgressbar', variable=variable_1)
pbar_1.pack()


# Progress bar #2
style_2 = ttk.Style(root)
style_2.layout('text.Horizontal.TProgressbar',
               [('Horizontal.Progressbar.trough',
                 {'children': [('Horizontal.Progressbar.pbar',
                                {'side': 'left', 'sticky': 'ns'})],
                  'sticky': 'nswe'}),
                ('Horizontal.Progressbar.label', {'sticky': ''})])
style_2.configure('text.Horizontal.TProgressbar', text='0 %')
variable_2 = tk.DoubleVar(root)
pbar_2 = ttk.Progressbar(root, style='text.Horizontal.TProgressbar', variable=variable_2)
pbar_2.pack()


def increment():
    # This dosn't change pbar_2's value, as it should act.
    pbar_1.step()

    # Why does this style_1.configure also change the text from style_2 as well???
    style_1.configure('text.Horizontal.TProgressbar', text='{:g} %'.format(variable_1.get()))
    root.after(200, increment)


increment()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get this weird behavior because you use the same layout. To fix this change the name of the second layout. In this case I added '1' to the name : `'text.Horizontal.TProgressbar1'`

```
style_2 = ttk.Style(root)
style_2.layout('text.Horizontal.TProgressbar1',
               [('Horizontal.Progressbar.trough',
                 {'children': [('Horizontal.Progressbar.pbar',
                                {'side': 'left', 'sticky': 'ns'})],
                  'sticky': 'nswe'}),
                ('Horizontal.Progressbar.label', {'sticky': ''})])
                
style_2.configure('text.Horizontal.TProgressbar1', text='0 %')
variable_2 = tk.DoubleVar(root)

pbar_2 = ttk.Progressbar(root, style='text.Horizontal.TProgressbar1', variable=variable_2)
pbar_2.pack()
```

Comment: I tried that earlier and both progress bars broke. I tried it again after you suggested it again and it worked, I must have missed something lol. Thanks, and welcome to Stackoverflow!

Answer (score 1):

Both of your scrollbars are using the same layout named "text.Horizontal.TProgressbar". When you change that layout, it will change all widgets that use that layout.

The fact that you're using `style_1` and `style_2` doesn't matter. What matters is the name of the layout you are configuring.